# Python's sum() will add lists of strings together. Any use?

Tags: python, sum

I ran across a strange Python idiom (to my eyes, anyway) and was certain it was a bug. But then it ran.

```
>>> sum([['a'], ['b']], [])
['a', 'b']
```

It is essentially the same as

```
>>> [] + ['a'] + ['b']
['a', 'b']
```

sum()'s default value is 0, but it lets you specify a different default, and in this case it must be another list (empty or otherwise).

It's really just a convoluted way of saying

```
>>> ['a'] + ['b']
['a', 'b']
```

which is simpler and easier to read.

So is there a performance difference?

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase

>>> lower = list(ascii_lowercase)
>>> upper = list(ascii_uppercase)

>>> timeit.timeit('lower + upper', globals=globals())
0.3070615209871903

>>> timeit.timeit('sum([lower, upper], [])', globals=globals())
0.7599097189959139
```

Yep, but not in a good way, so nothing to recommend there.

Are there any other uses for sum()'s ability to add objects?

Comment: Well, clearly sum's ability to add `int` and `float` objects is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sum([['a'], ['b']], [])
```

Here `sum` simply does what it is designed to do. Simply uses addition operator on its inputs. In this case, the inputs are two lists and the lists happen to have `__add__` method defined in them.

```
>>> [].__add__
<method-wrapper '__add__' of list object at 0x108f5c948>
```

The performance impact you see is because of the intermediate lists being created. When you do `[] + ['a']`, there is a new list created, with just `'a'`. When you add `'b'` to it, another list will be created.

---

Apart from that, the doc recommends alternatives to [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum),

> For some use cases, there are good alternatives to `sum()`. The preferred, fast way to concatenate a sequence of strings is by calling `''.join(sequence)`. To add floating point values with extended precision, see `math.fsum()`. To concatenate a series of iterables, consider using `itertools.chain()`.

In your case, you are trying to concatenate a series of iterables, the preferred way is to use `itertools.chain()`.

Comment: Curiously, in the example from my question, using `itertools.chain()` is much slower. `timeit.timeit('list(chain(lower, upper))', globals=globals())` -> `2.0641570200095885`

Answer (score 0):

as the name suggest sum is for summing up the elements, generally list of integers. Its not only for lists, one can pass iterator to it.